# Using position on nested XSLT to get analogous row

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a fairly complex XML input, and inside of it I have a table that I need to transform using XSLT to merge two attributes. So, on the table I have

```
<row>
   <entry align="left">
      <para>1234</para>
   </entry>
   <entry align="left">
       <para>TITLE OF DATA 1</para>
   </entry>
   <entry align="left">
       <entry>DESCRIPTION OF DATA 1</para>
   </entry>
   <entry align="left">
       <para>NOTES FOR DATA 1</para>
   </entry>
   <!-- Section -->
   <entry align="left">
       <para>SECTION 1</para>
       <para>SECTION 2</para>
   </entry>
   <!-- Sub-Section --> 
   <entry align="left">
       <para>11</para>
       <para>12</para>
   </entry>
</row>
```

I need to display these on a different data, but the section and subsection need to merged in a single line like **Section 1/11  Section 2/12**. I'm trying to do the following transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="row">
    <!-- Other stuff -->
    <title>
       <xsl:value-of select="entry[2]/para"/>
    </title>
    <section>
        Section/Subsection:
        <xsl:for-each select="entry[5]/para">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>/<xsl:value-of select="../../entry[6]/para[position()]"/> 
         </xsl:for-each>
    </section>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this shows up as **Section 1/11  Section 2/11**. Is there any better way to do this transformation. One important note is that I cannot change the input at all.

Comment: There is nothing in your XML other than position to distinguish a section from a subsection.  If that is the case then this is a really badly designed schema.  Show a complete example of the output you're expecting from the given input.

Comment: I agree that this is a bad design of the input, and that is not the only problem. However, it is like it is and we can change it. However, the size of the table is fixed, so the section and subsection will always be on the positions 5 and 6. It was fine because previously we had only one section and subsection, but now that we have two we need to adapt.As the input is very long, I'll use the same example above to show what's the expected output:


    <title>
       TITLE 1
    </title>
    <section>
        Section/Subsection: Section 1/11 Section 2/11
    </section>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am mostly guessing here, but try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry[5]/para">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>/<xsl:value-of select="../../entry[6]/para[$i]"/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```